# 8.13 LAB: Elements in a range

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
input_range = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]

for number in input_numbers:
    if input_range[0] <= number <= input_range[1]:
        print('{}'.format(number), end = ' ')
```

It should read in two lists of numbers, (where the second list has two values representing a range), and then print numbers from the first list that are between the two numbers in the second list. I want to print all these values with commas after each (including after the last one).

For example, if I input `25 51 0 200 33` and then `0 50`, the output should be `25,0,33,`.

However, I currently get `25 0 33` instead. How can I fix it so that the commas are printed?

Comment: Just use `end = ','`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple ways to solve this:

- Use `end=','` in your print statement, as suggested by @unmitigated
- Use the comma inside string to be printed and set `end=''` so that there is no separation space:
  `print('{},'.format(number), end = '')`

This is beyond your original question but should always give `input()` a string to inform the user what is being requested from them. In your example,

```
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input('Input numbers: ').split(' ')]
input_range = [int(x) for x in input('Input range: ').split(' ')]
```

Also, in Python there is another way to do the filtering using a list comprehension. The code is actually uglier and wouldn't make sense to use it in this case, but I'm including it for reference anyway. One

```
print(','.join([str(n) for n in input_numbers
                if input_range[0] <= number <= input_range[1]] + ',', end='')
```

(The `+ ','` and `end=''` are needed because the problem statement explicitly said, respectively, to "follow each output integer by a comma, *even the last one*" and to "not end with newline".)